# How to store email template HTML in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, blob, blobstore

I want to store email template HTML in mongoDB Collection. What is the best datatype to store the HTML? Can I store HTML as a blob field? I am using PHP for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
$document = array(
                    'name' => $_POST['campaignName'], 
                    'datetime' => $scheduleDate,
                    'from_name' => $_POST['fromName'], 
                    'from_email' => $_POST['fromEmail'], 
                    'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
                    'content' => new MongoBinData($_POST['designHtml']),
                    'contact_ids' => json_encode($contacts)
                );
```

I have prepared the document to save as above.

Comment: Do you trust your users not to be malicious? Technically you can save data however you like, but generally you would want to do some validation and sanity checks before saving the results in a database.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie Please suggest me how I can do the filtering. I am new to MongoDB, is this something like mysql real escape?